# wadl2java - Single WADL resources element is expected

Tags: java, rest, web-services, wadl

Im not able to use wadl2java and I really need to convert my wadl's to java, it gives me the following exception: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Single WADL resources element is expected**

I searched in the internet and found an answer to that problem but it doesn't work, since my namespace is correct.

what I found:
[How to create a client app for a RESTful service from wadl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492866/how-to-create-a-client-app-for-a-restful-service-from-wadl)

I have some projects from SoapUI and I tried to use the wadl2java tool that SoapUI has: https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/code-generation.html
I followed the instructions, downloaded the project, the project had some errors but resolved it thanks to the issue tracker.
after configuring that, when I do the wadl2java in SoapUI it says success but doesn't do a thing...

I tried the maven plugin too that gives me the exception I said above.

I tried downloading the apache cxf and use the wadl2java but same as above...

is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the path to the WADL file you want to create the Java code from. That's the one [mandatory parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_command_wadl.html).

If you still get this error, there may be an issue with the WADL file itself, see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/gentle-introduction-wadl-java).